# Dynamic Row height for a cell that has a scrollview loading an image in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In UITablView For rows that contain an image, how to figure out an appropriate height.

For the other rows in table, one can just let them automatically figure their own. I have a scrollview in the cell that dynamically adds imageView once i get the image from the url.

height (using autolayout) by returning UITableViewAutomaticDimension from
heightForRowAtIndexPath.

code for my imageViewCell is give below

```
class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var imageURL: NSURL? {
        didSet {
            cellImage = nil
            fetchImage()
        }
    }
    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!{
        didSet {
            scrollView.contentSize = cellImageView.frame.size
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.03
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
            scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    private func fetchImage() {
        if let url = imageURL {
            spinner?.startAnimating()
            let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0)) {
                () -> Void in
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if url == self.imageURL {
                        if imageData != nil {
                            self.cellImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        } else {
                            self.cellImage = nil
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private var cellImageView = UIImageView()
    private var cellImage: UIImage? {
        get { return cellImageView.image }
        set {
            cellImageView.image = newValue
            cellImageView.sizeToFit()
            scrollView?.contentSize = cellImageView.frame.size
            spinner?.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the image from your imageView from your cell and get the height of your image and use it in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
var cellHeight = cell.yourImageView.image?.size.height
```